# Asp.Net Core 2.1 - Upload file without using IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm migrating a solution from .NET Framework MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC. I need to upload files without using the Model Binding neither IFormFile interfaces.

I search in Google but it seems it's impossible to do this.

The code I try to convert is the follow

```
var file = Request.Files[key];

if (file == null)
     return null;

Stream inputStream = file.InputStream;
string contentType = file.ContentType;
string filename = file.FileName;
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to go against model binding for this?

Comment: I made an API where a client can pass data through variable and files. A request is composed by some FormData parameters a Json file and additional files. All files type can be encrypted or compressed and I have a function that performs decryption and/or uncompression.

Comment: Then don't fight the framework you chose and change your decryption/decompression code.

Comment: Ok I'll rewrite the functions. Does the model binding used for Asp.Net MVC Core (ActionResult Function (IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)  exists for Asp .Net MVC .NET Framework?